# is it possible to exclude footer.html which is included in base.html when I extend base.html/for django

Tags: html, django

In my base.html, I have `{% include 'footer.html' %}` and I extend base.html to every page of mine. But for some pages I don't want footer to be there. Is it possible to exclude that footer using some block key word?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a `block` in your `base.html`:

```
# base.html
...
{% block footer %}
    {% include 'footer.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

And then in a template where you don't want footer, do this:

```
# Some template
{% block footer %}
{% endblock %}
```